# SQL Selecting two tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which are related to each other in my mysql database, the users and the user_info. users table contains the username, password etc. while my user_info table contains basic information of users like lastname, firstname, etc. I was wondering how to display one row which will came from both tables without using two select statement.

It is something like this: (I know this is not the correct format. sorry)

```
SELECT * FROM users AND user_info WHERE users.user_id == user_info.user_id
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is an `inner join`.

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
INNER JOIN User_Info on Users.User_Id = User_Info.User_Id
```

You can read more about select statements, joins, etc. here:
[MySQL Reference - Select Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT users.user_id, user_info.user_id 
FROM users, user_info 
WHERE users.user_id = user_info.user_id;
```